# Getting auto incremented id from table after inserting row

Tags: jquery, database, codeigniter

Model:

```
$data = array( 'firstname' => $fname,
               'lastname' => $lname );

$result = $this->db->insert('users',$data);
```

Say that code inserted a new row. On the table, i have 3 columns, id,username,pass.
The id is auto incremented. After inserting, how would i be able to retrieve the id of that newly inserted row. Assuming that i am inserting atleast 2 rows and with the same firstname or last name.

This is what im planning, im not sure yet if it will work.

```
$sql = $this->db
    ->select('id')
    ->where(' ', $variable)
    ->from('user')
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

Im not sure what to put on my where clause since it may have rows with the same firstname and last names. I need to get the auto incremented id of my newly inserted row. The id is also my PK.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by usingL `$this->db->insert_id();`

```
$result = $this->db->insert('users',$data);
$latest_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Read more ate [Query Helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

But if you are inserting multiple files using `insert_batch()` this will not work, it will only get the last inserted id from the batch.SO if you are planning to insert multiple data you need a `forloop` then do the normal insert while saving the inserted key in array sample

```
foreach($data as $v)
{
     //prep data colum name as key ,value as value
     $input['firstname'] = $v->firstname;
     $input['lastname'] = $v->lastname;

     //insert
     $this->db->insert('users',$input);
     //store keys in array
     $inserted_ids[] = $this->db->insert_id();

}

print_r($inserted_ids);
```

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but from the name itself. is it a built in function? if yes, then does it mean to retrieve the latest inserted id on my table?

Comment: @user3205047 yes, retrieve the latest inserted id.

Comment: Thank you. Ill be accepting your answer. Where does it located in the ci documentation?

Comment: @user3205047 added the link

Comment: does the $latest_id variable contain only the latest inserted right? so it should be fine if i store it in an array since im inserting multiple values and putting it inside an foreachloop.

Comment: @user3205047 yup, thats a way to do it, look at my edit